# Do ideals partition a ring?

Tags: ring-theory

Say we have two principal ideals- $(a)$ and $(b)$. Is $r_{1}*a=r_{2}*b$ possible for $r_{1},r_{2}\in R$, with $(a) \neq (b)$?
I don't see a problem with this as long as the multiplicative inverses of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are not present in $R$.

Edit: Clarification- in other words, if $(a) \neq (b)$, is $(a)\bigcap (b)$ always $=\phi$?

Comment: How is the title connected to the question?

Comment: If ideals did always partition a ring, then the concept of intersection of ideals would be moot...

Comment: The intersection of two ideals is always an ideal. Ideals are never empty. (In fact, every ideal contains the element $0$, which gives a trivial solution to your equation: $0a=0b=0$.)

Comment: @Dennis: If $r_1*a\neq r_2*b$ for all $r_1,r_2,a,b\in R$, then $(a)\cap(b)=\varnothing$ if $a\neq b$, so the principal (left) ideals would indeed give a partition of $R$. Problem is, every ring has a $0$, so such a partition is possible only for $R=(0)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way posted, the you actually ask whether it is possible that $(a)\cap(b)\neq(0)$. The answer is yes: take any commutative ring $R$, and $r_1=b$ and $r_2=a$.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I got my answer.